# How to use an image with Responsive Image style as a background?

Tags: 8, media, theming

We have a need to use the [Responsive Image](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/mobile-guide/responsive-images-in-drupal-8) module. The key is that we want to be able to use the image (field_image) field with Responsive Image styles as a background and put the node's title on top of them.

How can we achieve this?

We have tried the following but this only fetches the original photo in a twig template. In other words, when i use Chrome Dev tools to see if it fetched the other images as part of the Responsive Image style settings, it does not fetch them.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper__image" style="background-image: url('{{file_url(content.field_image.0['#item'].entity.uri.value)}}>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper__content"> {# title goes here #} </div>
</div>
```

Sample image:
[image: Image with text on top]

Currently we are using the out of the box [Responsive Image twig template](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21responsive_image%21templates%21responsive-image.html.twig/8.3.x)

```
{% if output_image_tag %}
  {{ img_element }}
{% else %}
  <picture>
    {% if sources %}
      {#
      Internet Explorer 9 doesn't recognise source elements that are wrapped in
      picture tags. See http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/#ie9
      #}
      <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
      {% for source_attributes in sources %}
        <source{{ source_attributes }}/>
      {% endfor %}
      <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
    {% endif %}
    {# The controlling image, with the fallback image in srcset. #}
    {{ img_element }}
  </picture>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I had to do the same thing and I just used a `position: absolute` image & title. I don't believe the `picture` element of the `srcset` is supported in CSS or anything of the like.

Comment: I am just curious as I have not used the Responsive Image module... But I do know that you need to use a twig filter to call an image style in a twig template like that, e.g. `file_url(content.field_image.0['#item'].entity.uri.value) | image_style('responsive_style')`. Installing the module "Twig Tweak" makes this filter available. I wonder if Drupal would replace the image as long as that filter was applied??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying isn't going to work on a background image. You'd need to do this yourself with javascript. How i've done it previously is added data attributes to the div for each breakpoint e.g.

```
<div data-mobile-image="mobilestylename/aaa.jpg" data-desktop-image="desktopstylename/aaa.jpg">
```

Then in javscript use matchmedia or a body class if its already being added by your theme to know which breakpoint you are in and then do

```
var mobile_image = $('.mydiv').data('mobile-image');
$('.mydiv').css('background-image',mobile_image);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let the responsive image markup from the core :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper__image">{{ content.field_image }}</div>
  <div class="wrapper__content"> {# title goes here #} </div>
</div>
```

And use the CSS property [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) on your responsive image :

```
.wrapper__image {
  position: relative;
  width : 100%
  height : 100vh
}

.wrapper__image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.wrapper__image img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can easily find JavaScript polyfills to enable this feature on IE.